# How jasmine works with Async Test

Tags: javascript, testing, asynchronous, jasmine

All:

I am pretty new to Jasmine testing, one question I am wondering about async test is:

Could anybody give a brief explanation how does Jasmine know there is a done() function call inside and waiting for that finish?

For example, if I put some async call in beforeEach:

```
var flag = false;
beforeEach(function(done){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // some task here
        flag = true;
        done();
    }, 3000)
})

it("Should be true if the async call has completed", function () {
    expect(flag).toEqual(true);
});
```

How Jasmine know it should let that `it` spec test wait?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasmine knows this because you supply the done argument. If you don't have an async call you should omit the done parameter.

```
beforeEach(function(){
    nonAsyncMethod();
})
```